# How to convert image URI to Byte[](Byte array) in React Native

Tags: image, react-native, file-upload, react-native-image-picker

I need to upload image to server. The server require image in byte array. I'm using `react-native-image-picker` to select image from device. It returns URI(image path), which I need to convert to byte Array. Is there any way to image path to byte array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-native-image-picker` provides option for base64 string. Set `includeBase64`  prop to `true`. You will get base64 encoded string in response.

Comment: could you explain how a base64 string is related to a byte array?